# Assign fixed number of variables to elements in variable length list

Tags: python, variable-assignment, iterable-unpacking

Background:

I have a python script to check working hours of employees. Each employee has morning and afternoon shifts, with lunch time in between, and each time they put the finger a new timestamp is recorded.

So, depending on the time of each day, there may be from zero to four timestamps in the list for that day.

The question: "How can I 'unpack' timestamps to the respective variables avoiding all this ugly, duplicated code?"

```
morning_entry = None
morning_leave = None
afternoon_entry = None
afternoon_leave = None

timestamps = get_timestamps()

if timestamps:
    morning_entry = timestamps.pop(0)

if timestamps:
    morning_leave = timestamps.pop(0)

if timestamps:
    afternoon_entry = timestamps.pop(0)

if timestamps:
    afternoon_leave = timestamps.pop(0)
```

Comment: `pop()` removes the last element from the list. Not obvious design choice imo.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: but `timestamps.pop()` is mutating `timestamps`.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: as DSM pointed out, I am taking off one element at a time and assigning it. This works exactely as I want, but is obviously very ugly and violates DRY badly (imagine a longer list of variables...)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I cannot see how your suggestion is better. Please post an answer with some code so that I can better understand it and perhaps accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution but may not be that elegant

```
morning_entry,morning_leave,afternoon_entry,afternoon_leave=(timestamps+[None]*4)[:4]
```

Just pad it with Nones before the list and then slice

Comment: I actually used `= timestamps + [None]*(4-len(timestamps))`, but that is personal preference. Either approach works! Thanks!

Comment: (also, note that my actual code should use `pop(0)`, which I forgot to type the first time I wrote the question, but now that is corrected. That is important because otherwise I get the wrong order)

Comment: Ah!! actually I thought that while typing my answer but then saw that u r poping it from backside, then I changed the variable order

Answer (score 0):

An `itertools`-based version of [Sainath's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26279066/1126841):

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

(morning_entry,
 morning_leave,
 afternoon_entry,
 afternoon_leave) = chain(timestamps, repeat(None, 4))
```

Whether it is more elegant is debatable; it does have the minor improvement that `timestamps` is not restricted to any particular type of iterable.